# How to compare text in TextView with String value

Tags: java, android-studio

This question has been asked severally and I collected all the answers and tried them but it is not really working for me. 
I have a TextView which displays one of these names at a time:
**Joseph99,
Thomas79,
Marry29,
Matthew21**

Below this TextView I have a button. What I want is this, When TextView displays for example this name: Joseph99, i want the button to change its text to: Yes

If any other name is displayed on the TextView I want the button to say: NO.
For now the button actually does nothing I just want it to change text to either YES or NO depends on what is displayed on a TextView.

I have tried the following in the **onCreate();**

```
final textview = tv.getText().toString();
final String str1 = "Joseph99";
final String str2 = "Thomas79"
final String str3 = "Marry29"
final String str4 = "Matthew21"

if(str1.matches(textview)){
button.setText("YES");
}else{button.setText("NO");}
```

On the above code the text matches but I am getting a NO on a button even if the text on TextView is equal to str1. I also tried .equals like below:

```
if(str1.equals(textview)){
button.setText("YES");
}else{button.setText("NO");}
```

But I still get the NO even if the TextView has same text with str1.

I also tried this code:

```
if(!textview.getText().toString().matches("Joseph99");
```

And also this:

```
if(!textview.getText().toString().equals("Joseph99")
```

But the button text does not change, it is always NO, whether the **TextView** displays **Joseph99** or not.

Note: The data which shows on TextView comes from **SharedPreferences** and it changes time by time.

There might be an error on my code but its three days now trying to figure out, but I have failed

Comment: Can you try logging `textview` and telling us what you get? Might be a case of white spaces and/or uppercase vs lowercase letters, or something like that?

Comment: I have tried your code below still I get a NO

Comment: What I asked was that you try using `Log` to show the value of `textview` in the logcat and telling us what you see. I didn't offer any code.

Comment: Okay i will do this soon had left for a relief,

Answer (score 0):

Well I will highly recommend you to debug and see as everything seems correct but I think it’s the issue with white-spaces

Try this

```
 if(str1.equals(textview.trim())){button.setText("YES");}else{button.setText("NO");}
```